# Advanced curve fitting methods that allows real-time monitoring

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I'm using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` to fit a somewhat complicated curve.

Sometimes the optimization fails, and no useful information is returned. Is it possible to make `curve_fit()` return the current fitting parameters every few hundred iterations? I think it might be helpful for evaluating the fitting.

If not, is there a package that allows you to do this? Or should I consider extending `curve_fit()` on my own?

I'm looking for something like:

`list = curve_fit(function, parameters, update_frequency=100)`

```py
list = [[popt_100, pcov_100],
        [popt_200, pcov_200],
        [popt_300, pcov_300],
        ...]
```

So I can plot the fitting at different points and see the progress even if the optimization fails.

Comment: If you iterate,  setting the "maxfev" parameter to curve_fit() as 100, you might print the results and then run again using those fitted parameters as the p0 initial parameter estimates for the next iteration. I have never tried this but I think it should work.

Comment: @James Phillips I just tried setting maxfev = 100. Optimal parameters were not found and nothing was returned, and I couldn't get the last try parameters.

Comment: I also tried this just now using "scipy.seterr(all='warn')" to convert the exception to a warning so that something might be returned - no luck, it did not work. I apologize for the bad suggestion.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thanks for trying, I'm considering extending curve_fit. I hope I can come up with something useful.